# update progress bar using ajax request seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax

Basicaly, I'm performing an AJAX request for an external login system, how can I update the progress bar based on the length of the request?

For example, the request takes between **1.30s** to **1.40s** to complete, how can I update an progress bar based on certain intervals, like update it 10% every 10ms or something, here's the HTML layout for the progress bar

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="65" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 65%">
        <span class="sr-only">65% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The length of the progress bar is determined using the `width: 65%` attribute

The idea is to basically get it to look like it's updating based on the request so when the request is complete the percentage bar is full

Comment: My suggestion would be to not. At 1.3 to 1.4 seconds (in most cases), the user is hardly going to be thinking 'I wonder how long I've got left until I'm finished logging in'. Use a [loader gif](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=loader+gif).

Comment: How do you know the request is going to take 1.3-1.4 and not 6 seconds on a slow connection?

Comment: @KevinB Was that aimed at the OP?

Comment: @Kevin B i quess he meant that the server procceses the request for ~1.5s

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think this post is quite clear
http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Posting this for future reference (should the blog be removed):

```
$.ajax({
     xhr: function(){
       var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
       //Upload progress
       xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
       if (evt.lengthComputable) {
         var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
         //Do something with upload progress
         console.log(percentComplete);
         }
       }, false);
     //Download progress
       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
         if (evt.lengthComputable) {
           var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
         //Do something with download progress
           console.log(percentComplete);
         }
       }, false);
       return xhr;
     },
     type: 'POST',
     url: "/",
     data: {},
     success: function(data){
    //Do something success-ish
    }
 });
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)
Also: if this is indeed the answer to your problem, mark it that way :) so that it is clear for everyone your problem is solved :)

Comment: Thanks @Yoeri! @Curtis, you should mark the answer as correct, I might have found it more quickly that way...

Comment: I tried using above code , does not work for me. it looks like ```evt.lengthComputable``` doesnot work.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502943/jquery-ajax-progress-via-xhr

Comment: Would this work if I'm using `.load` instead of `.ajax`?

Comment: I don't think so. The syntax to get the xhr object is a bit different:
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {.. })). This is only executed after the request has been completed.

Comment: `percentComplete` hits 100 way before my `success` function is called. Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: nope, no direct idea. you could post this as a seperate question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when using FormData and uploading a file, as it returns 1 almost instantly wen clearly the file is still being uploaded and success hasn't even been called yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery form [plugin](https://github.com/jquery-form/form) and use this method '**uploadProgress**' like this:

```
$('#register-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        url: url,
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete){
            $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');
            $('.progress-bar > p').html(percentComplete);
        },
        success: function (response, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            // TODO: You'll need to do some custom logic here to handle a successful
            // form post, and when the form is invalid with validation errors.
        },
        error: function(a, b, c) {
            // NOTE: This callback is *not* called when the form is invalid.
            // It is called when the browser is unable to initiate or complete the ajax submit.
            // You will need to handle validation errors in the 'success' callback.
            console.log(a, b, c);
        }
    });
});
```