# Monitor AJAX JSON Object download/transfer progress

Tags: ajax, json, download

I would like to know if it is possible to create a progress bar for an AJAX call where data returned is a JSON Object which represents a large database . This functions is used to synchronize between a client - server side database, and would like to show progress for users, like a normal file download...

I have tried the following without sucesss..

```
$.ajax({
xhr: function() {
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress, false);       

 function updateProgress (oEvent) {
      if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total * 100;
        console.log(percentComplete);
          } else {
         console.log('Unable to compute Size');
         }
    }
   return xhr;
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "http:s......"
    ect....//
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably using - XMLHttpRequest
I'm trying to achieve the same so digging it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).
Does **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502943/jquery-ajax-progress-via-xhr)** work for you?