# Show the progress of the file in Ajax. what's wrong with the code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, progress-bar, form-submit

The following code works and sends the browsed file but somehow it just doesn't show me the progress while sending the file when it takes time to send a big file...
When I browse a big file and hit submit, the form waits for 20 seconds and than gives me the "success part" but I am trying to show the progress of the process so the user won't think that it just doesn't work and leave the page before it sends the form to my email:

```
    $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/sendFile",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { filename: file.filename, data: file.data, "name": name, "email": email, "phone": phone, "fromLanguage": fromLanguage, "toLanguage": toLanguage },

  beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                        XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                $("#serviceForm").hide().html(percentComplete + "%");
                            }
                        }, false); 
                    },
                            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                                $("#serviceForm").hide().html("<div align='center' style='font-size:200%'>Thank you very much!</div>").fadeIn(3000);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: I don't think `uploadProgress` is a thing. The underlying xhr object has a `progress` event, but I'm not sure if you can link it like this through jQuery.

Comment: Related question: [jQuery Ajax progress via XHR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502943/jquery-ajax-progress-via-xhr)

Comment: i still don't get it how to make something while it loads...

Comment: i have just updated the code... still doesn't work well.