# How to show real download progress for a json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I was trying to show some real time progress bar for a large json data, while it gets fully downloaded.

Is it possible?

I tried using XMLHttpRequest.

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success")
    }
});
```

Here, evt.lengthComputable is coming as false. Is there any way to show real time progress bar for json data?

Comment: An excellent answer was provided here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22504560/101662

Comment: I think `lengthComputable` is empty because browser does not know total size of your data. Try adding a `Content-Length` header?

Comment: @LeoNyx Is it possible if Content-Length header is available?

Comment: Do you have any url with content length header?

Comment: Pretty much any static file on the internet is served with `Content-Length`. Your local development server will surely do, too.