# Size of json object? (in KBs/MBs)

Tags: javascript, json

How can I know that how much data is transferred over wire in terms of size in kilobytes, megabytes?

Take for example

```
{
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2
}
```

How do I know what is the size of this payload is and **not** the length or items in the object

**UPDATE**

```
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:application/json
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: Depends on your encoding, what is it?

Comment: Also depends on if your webserver is automatically gzipping responses...

Comment: Also depends on compression, gzip is very common for transferring json.

Comment: There is still barely any detail here. How are you transmitting the JSON? Where is your code? If you're passing it as a string yourself (rather than some library serialising it for you) then simply count the number of characters in the string, after applying Unicode magicks as described in answers below.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

An answer to the actual question should include the bytes spent on the headers and should include taking gzip compression into account, but I will ignore those things.

You have a few options. They all output the same answer when run:

**If Using a Browser or Node (Not IE)**

```js
const size = new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(obj)).length
const kiloBytes = size / 1024;
const megaBytes = kiloBytes / 1024;
```

If you need it to work on IE, you can use a [pollyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder#Polyfill)

**If Using Node**

```js
const size = Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

(which is the same as `Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(obj), "utf8")`).

**Shortcut That Works in IE, Modern Browsers, and Node**

```js
const size = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(obj)).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
```

That last solution will work in almost every case, but that last solution will throw a `URIError: URI malformed` exception if you feed it input containing a string that should not exist, like `let obj = { partOfAnEmoji: ""[1] }`. The other two solutions I provided will not have that weakness.

(*Credits:* Credit for the first solution goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34332105/1838240).
Credit for the second solution goes to the [utf8-byte-length](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8-byte-length) package (which is good, you could use that instead).
Most of the credit for that last solution goes to [here](https://github.com/substack/utf8-length/blob/master/index.js), but I simplified it a bit.
I found the test suite of the [utf8-byte-length](https://github.com/parshap/utf8-byte-length) package super helpful, when researching this.)

Answer (score 22):

For ascii, you can count the characters if you do...

```
JSON.stringify({
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2
}).length
```

If you have special characters too, you can pass through a function for calculating length of UTF-8 characters...

```
function lengthInUtf8Bytes(str) {
  // Matches only the 10.. bytes that are non-initial characters in a multi-byte sequence.
  var m = encodeURIComponent(str).match(/%[89ABab]/g);
  return str.length + (m ? m.length : 0);
}
```

Should be accurate...

```
var myJson = JSON.stringify({
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 'Máybë itß nºt that sîmple, though.'
})

// simply measuring character length of string is not enough...
console.log("Inaccurate for non ascii chars: "+myJson.length)

// pass it through UTF-8 length function...
console.log("Accurate for non ascii chars: "+ lengthInUtf8Bytes(myJson))

/* Should echo...

Inaccurate for non ascii chars: 54
Accurate for non ascii chars: 59

*/
```

### [Working demo](http://codepen.io/billymoon/pen/JtjqH)

Comment: Máybë itß nºt that sîmple, though.

Comment: @AlexWayne you could combine with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5515960/665261

Comment: `If you multiply this by 8 you should get bytes for ascii strings.` Why multiply by 8?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because it is late :)

Comment: @BillyMoon: You mean... because it is l8? ;)

Comment: That produces an inaccurate answer for `lengthInUtf8Bytes("")`. It should output `4`, but it outputs `5`

Answer (score 20):

Here is a function which does the job.

```js
function memorySizeOf(obj) {
    var bytes = 0;

    function sizeOf(obj) {
        if(obj !== null && obj !== undefined) {
            switch(typeof obj) {
            case 'number':
                bytes += 8;
                break;
            case 'string':
                bytes += obj.length * 2;
                break;
            case 'boolean':
                bytes += 4;
                break;
            case 'object':
                var objClass = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
                if(objClass === 'Object' || objClass === 'Array') {
                    for(var key in obj) {
                        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                        sizeOf(obj[key]);
                    }
                } else bytes += obj.toString().length * 2;
                break;
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    };

    function formatByteSize(bytes) {
        if(bytes < 1024) return bytes + " bytes";
        else if(bytes < 1048576) return(bytes / 1024).toFixed(3) + " KiB";
        else if(bytes < 1073741824) return(bytes / 1048576).toFixed(3) + " MiB";
        else return(bytes / 1073741824).toFixed(3) + " GiB";
    };

    return formatByteSize(sizeOf(obj));
};

console.log(memorySizeOf({"name": "john"}));
```

I got the snippet from following URL

> https://gist.github.com/zensh/4975495

Comment: Not accurate.. Even for utf8 gives higher numbers

Answer (score 2):

`Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj)).length` will give you the number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>JSON-objects are Javascript-objects, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size) already shows a way to calculate the rough size.</strike> <- See Comments/Edits

EDIT: Your actual question is quite difficult as even if you could access the headers, content-size doesn't show the gzip'ed value as far as I know.

If you're lucky enough to have a good html5 browser, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139613/update-progress-bar-using-ajax-request-seconds) contains a nice piece of code:

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   //Upload progress
   xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
   if (evt.lengthComputable) {
     var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
     //Do something with upload progress
     console.log(percentComplete);
     }
   }
```

Therefore the following should work (can't test right now):

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
  alert(xhr.total);
}
```

Note that XMLHttpRequest is native and doesn't require jQuery.

Next EDIT:

I found a [kind-of duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097712/how-can-i-use-deflated-gzipped-content-with-an-xhr-onprogress-function) (slightly diffrent question, pretty much same answer). The important part for this question is

```
content_length = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("X-Content-Length");
```

Where jqXHR is your XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: Do not simply link to another answer in yours. If you feel this question is a duplicate of another, flag it as such.

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough :/

Comment: No, JSON objects are _not_ JavaScript objects. The answer you link to is wrong for that reason, and also because it doesn't even attempt to count bytes in a lexical (string) representation.

Comment: @Sebb Your reputation *is* high enough to flag.